# Edit page title only (not name), in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How do I edit only the title of a page (not the name)?

I add a page and it asks for a name, I provide "*about-us*" as name and it then names the page as `about-us.aspx`. This is good and I have a clean URL. However, at the top it displays the same as the title in big bold letters. How do I edit it to "*about us*" (with spaces instead of hyphens)?

When I edit properties, I only get the option to change the name not the title. Elsewhere, I read that the "*title*" column is hidden and that I need to change the content type and make that column as "*required*" and change to category from "*_hidden*" to "*base type*". But, no matter what I try, am unable to get to edit the title property.

This is a team site with publishing features on, if that makes any difference.

Comment: you could use a "Pages" library wich is available when publishing features is on. There are few content types like "article page", "page" nad "welcome page". Using one of this CT you could write different Title and Name of pages.

Comment: Ahhh... thank you @martusha! I was adding a page from the *gear* icon > *Add a page*. Also, in team sites without publishing features, I am stuck. Nevertheless, this solves my purpose at least in publishing sites. Thanks again. I had been struggling with this for so many days now!

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, if it was helpful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a "Pages" library wich is available when publishing features is on. There are few content types like "article page", "page" nad "welcome page". Using one of this CT you could write different Title and Name of pages.
For not publishing sites there are used Site Pages library for pages creation, and it uses Wiki pages content types, there is Title only but no name field.

Comment: For non-publishing sites, there is *name* field, but no *title* field. Thanks anyway, it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well, but discovered that while the Page is in "Edit" mode, there is a "Rename Page" option available in the ribbon of the Page tab. Simply click that button and you can rename the page to whatever you want. This is on a team site that does not have publishing features enabled.

[image]

Comment: This also changes the FileLeafRef of the page - about-us.aspx and thus does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In SPO Team Sites as of July, 2019, pages have a Title field at the top. Whatever text you type there becomes the page title as well.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution under Site Contents, find your page name webpart, click on the 3 dots to see the webpart menu. This opens Settings, choose “List name, description and Navigation” and type in your new page name. Save and Close.